# Changing text size in response to cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to input accessibility into my site by including a button that allows the user to have the text grow so that it is easier to read. Then, so that they don't have to click the button every time the page loads it saves their response as a cookie

Upon clicking the button the cookie contents does not seem to change, I have tried to manually edit the cookie and that has proven to change nothing, I think the issue is with the checking of the cookie

```js
var check = checkCookie();
if (check === "true") {
  //add large text here
  $('.page-main').has("p").has("span").contents().addClass("enlarge");
} else if (check === "false") {
  //add small text here
  $('.page-main').has("p").has("span").contents().removeClass("enlarge");
} else {
  document.cookie = "TIDEtext=false; path=/";
}

$(".TEXT").click(function() {
  var check = checkCookie();
  if (check === "false") {
    document.cookie = "TIDEtext=true; path=/";
    //add large text here
    $('.page-main').has("p").has("span").contents().addClass("enlarge");
  } else if (check === "true") {
    document.cookie = "TIDEtext=false; path=/";
    //add small text here
    $('.page-main').has("p").has("span").contents().removeClass("enlarge");
  } else {
    document.cookie = "TIDEtext=false; path=/";
  }
});

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var text = getCookie("TIDEtext");
  if (text !== "") {
    var cName = "TIDEtext";
    getCookie(cName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes, which should work

```
function setCorrectTextSize(update) {
  var check = getCookie("TIDEtext");
  var showLargeText = false;
  var shouldUpdate = update !== undefined;

  if (check == "") {
    showLargeText = shouldUpdate ? true : false;
  } else if (check === "false") {
    showLargeText = shouldUpdate ? true : false;
  } else if (check === "true") {
    showLargeText = shouldUpdate ? false : true;
  } 
  if (showLargeText) {
  $('.page-main').has("p").has("span").contents().addClass("enlarge");
  } else {
  $('.page-main').has("p").has("span").contents().removeClass("enlarge");
  }
  if (shouldUpdate) {
         setCookie("TIDEtext", showLargeText?"true":"false", 60);
  }
}

$(".TEXT").click(function() {
    setCorrectTextSize(true);
});

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

setCorrectTextSize();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/67sg8f0g/3/

Comment: I just gave it a go and for some reason it will only work one way, i.e. start small and go big, once I press the button again it wont revert to its original size

Comment: I had some conflicting JS which was creating a duplicate of the true cookie which has since been fixed. However now when the text is small I look at the console it adds a true cookie but doesnt change the text

Comment: Got it to work by using inline css rather than the classes

Answer (score 0):

```
var check = checkCookie();
if (check === "true") {

function checkCookie() {
  var text = getCookie("TIDEtext");
  if (text !== "") {
    var cName = "TIDEtext";
    getCookie(cName);
  }
}
```

Your checkCookie() isn't returning the string 'true'.

If you change the function checkCookie() to return the boolean TRUE, and change the `if (check === "true")` to `if (check == true)` it should work.

Comment: Will I need to do the same to the false check at the top?

Comment: Oh, i didn't see that one. - But yes.

Comment: You can also instead of doing the if (check == true) just write if(check) .. It has the same meaning. Likewise in the false part, you can write it: if(!check)

Comment: Alright coolio, how would I change it to save the cookie as a bool rather than a string

Comment: You're not saving the cookie as a bool, but in your check you're returning the bool true if the cookie exist. 

Like: 

function checkCookie() {
  var text = getCookie("TIDEtext");
  if (text !== "" || text !== null) {
    var cName = "TIDEtext";
    getCookie(cName);

    return true;
  }
}

Comment: the last part; var cName = "TIDEtext";
    getCookie(cName); isn't neccesary - you're getting the Cookie when declaring your variable text in the top. So that part can be deleted, and then just return true if(text !== "") ..

Comment: inbetween the last two "}" you should also add a return false; så if that the cookie is not found, you're getting the bool false returned from the function.

Comment: Awesome, I shall give it a go and get back to you with the result :D

Comment: @TommyBeaton - Any response regarding this answer is accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem with [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

localstorage is much faster since the cookies will send the data on each http header. However there's a bit of a downside. You can't access the same value you stored in the localstorage set on http if you're in an https page and vice versa.

### Example

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //when page loads get value from local storage
    var fontsize = localStorage.fontSize;
    
    //set fontsize
    $('.textSize').css("font-size", fontsize + "px");
    $("#sizeControl").val(fontsize);
});

$("#sizeControl").change(function()
{
  //get the size value
  var fontsize = $(this).val();
  
  //update the font size
  $('.textSize').css("font-size", fontsize + "px");
  
  //use local storage to store the size value
  localStorage.fontSize = fontsize;
});
```

```css
.padded
{
  padding: 15px;
}

.bordered
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="padded bordered">
  <select class="padded" id="sizeControl">
    <option value="12"> small </option>
    <option value="18"> medium</option>
    <option value="24"> large </option>
  </select><br/>
  <p class="textSize">
    Some example text showing how a user can enlarge/save text using local storage
  </p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately stack snippets is sandboxed so we cant see it in the code snippet viewer. For this I created a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6goeddu/4/) for you to test this yourself: